# JSSOR SLIDER Image size set in options, but images don't obey and stay small

Tags: jssor

In my jssor slider, I changed the

```
$SlideWidth: 800, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
$SlideHeight: 442, //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
```

...but the images in the `slider1_container` are not sizing correctly. In my demo, the blue background is the container at 800 x 442 pixels, and my slide images should resize to fill that space.

The original image sizes are pretty big, at 1920 x 1012 pixels.

http://fwavetrading.com/slider-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. There was a container div I missed, with a width:600 and height:300. Problem solved.